# Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync() method does not work in outlook mac 2016

Tags: office-addins, office365-apps, office-js, outlook-web-addins

In office 365 outlook add-in, `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` method does not work in **outlook Mac**. But it works fine in **safari** and **chrome**.

office js reference is  "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"

here is the code of add-in read app

```
     var _item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
     var body = _item.body;
        // Get the body asynchronous as text
        body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            }
            else {
                $('#subject').html(asyncResult.value.trim());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That function is part of requirement set 1.3; the [Mac add ins only support requirement set 1.1](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/tutorial-api-requirement-sets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but there is a workaround. You could achieve this with makeEwsRequestAsync() method, which is provided in requirements set 1.1. This requires you to make a SOAP request and to parse the response data to get the email body. In the SOAP request, use:

```
    '        <t:AdditionalProperties>' +
    '            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:TextBody"/>' +
    '        </t:AdditionalProperties>' +
```

This will return a response that you can parse.

For reference:
https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/1.1/Office.context.mailbox.html#makeEwsRequestAsync

Comment: makeEwsRequestAsync() method also helpful to achieve same requirement .however it needs highest permission level.   `code  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>`